# Change file permission as part of Publish Web Site

Tags: asp.net, logging, publishing

I am working on an ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2005. I am using a trace listener to check the values of variables as I test the web application. Every time I publish the web site it overwrites the entire web site so I need to give my log file write permissions for the ASPNET account again. Is there a way to automate this chore as part of the publishing process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should simply put your log file on a different folder?

For example C:\temp
(Give ASPNET permission on this folder)

---

Additional resources:

How to change permissions from command line:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5210173_change-file-permissions-command-line.html

[Step-By-Step ASP.NET Automated Build/Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762/step-by-step-asp-net-automated-build-deploy)